# How do you separate a logic gate from the circuit implementing that logic gate?

Tags: transistors, logic-gates

[image]

I am a beginner in electronics with less than 2 weeks of actual experience and less than 6 months of study time.

In figure 1 I drew a circuit implementing the NAND logic, while in figure 2 I drew the actual NAND gate (transistors and resistors) separately from other components (switches, diode, battery) implementing the logic.

I tried the same with AND gat in figure 3 and figure 4. But it appeared to be impossible to separate the actual AND gate from the other components without breaking the circuit. This is because the output of the AND gate is connected in series with the rest of the circuit, unlike the output of the NAND gate which is connected in parallel. So I had to separate the AND gate by NOTting the output of a NAND gate, as can be seen in figure 4. It took me 3 transistors and 4 resistors instead of 2 transistors and 3 resistors.

Is there any way of separating the output of the AND gate made up of 2 transistors and 3 resistors, so that this output can be fed into other logic gates?

Comment: What does make fig-1 a NAND gate, and how would fig-3 be an AND gate?

Comment: @greybeard If the circuit depicted in figure 1 is built in breadboard it produces the 1110 truth table of the NAND gate, similarly the circuit depicted in figure 3 produces the 0001 truth table of the AND gate. I have just built them and have confirmed that they actually do.

Comment: Look up the CMOS "AND" gate implementation. This is the most used implementation these days in VLSI design.

Comment: you have an inconsistency in fig. 1 and fig. 3 ... fig. 1 output has to be high to light the LED ... fig. 3 the output has to be low to light the LED

Comment: You say *truth table*, I see bases "receiving" a current or none depending on switches and expect collector currents/voltages to change accordingly, the LED to emit significant light or not: What does make fig-1 a NAND gate? Does this "definition" allow outputs to be connected to inputs? Is fig-3 an AND gate *by the same token*?

Comment: Not every circuit admits being drawn as a logic gate.

Comment: @greybeard well that is what logic gates are supposed to do don't they? At least logic gates made on breadboard using bjts and resistors? Output current flows or doesn't depending on whether current flows through thd two inputs? Yes, by connecting output of one into inputs of others, using 4 NAND gates like in figure 2, I made an XOR gate. They can be chained. As I said I am an absolute beginner in this field, I have many misconceptions, I can easily be wrong, in that case I would like to be corrected and enlightened by people more exprrienced and more knowledgeable than me.

Comment: No, current flowing or not flowing does not make a circuit a logic gate in my book. Implementing a logic function in a way that allows to compose bigger functions does.

Comment: @greybeard I am not disagreeing with you. In fact that is what my question was. I could make NOT, NOR and NAND gates and chain them into each other. But I wasn't able to do the same with NONE, OR snd AND gate. So as an alterative I was making AND gate by NOTting the outout of NAND gate, was making OR gate by NOTting the output of NOR gate and so on. That however required me using one extra transistor and an extra resistor. So I asked whethrer there is a way of making AND and OR gate using 2 transistors and 3 resistors whose outputs can be fed back into other logic gates as inputs.

Comment: *Is there a way of making AND and OR gate using 2 transistors and 3 resistors whose outputs can be fed into other logic gates as inputs?* is a perfectly valid question. It should go in a question body!

Comment: @ARNOBChatterjee There is a way of making gates using only one BJT and resistors (RTL) where the outputs are designed to work together with the inputs. But there has to be a ***design process*** for that to work. Not slapping parts together without crafted thinking about input and output details. From just cursory observation of your diagrams, it doesn't look to me as though you care much whether it is 1, 2, or 3 BJTs. Do you really have a desire for a fixed number of BJTs (2?) per gate? What about power consumption? How much per gate?

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason this feels nonsensical is that your input and output are different types of logic signals. The input is 5V when high and 0V when low and current goes into the input. The output is 0V when high and 5V when low and current goes into the output. These inputs are not compatible with this output - you couldn't chain two of these gates together.

But who said 5V has to be high and 0V has to be low? As long as you remember the output is reversed, you can still draw a logic diagram for this circuit: it turns on the LED when A and B are both on:

```
         ____
        |    \
A ------| and \
        | gate |---LED
B ------|     /
        |____/
```

If you want the diagram to look a little more like the circuit, you could draw your gate as a NAND gate (it's the same gate, after all) and then show the LED wired between the 5V and the output, so the LED turns on when the output is low. You still can't chain these gates because the inputs want to have current put in and the output also wants to have current put in. (You *can* make that work if you use a low-value pull-up resistor to supply the current to both, but that isn't a very good design as it wastes lots of power)

Also remember the point of a diagram is to tell someone something. If you want to show someone what the circuit does, show them the diagram above (but draw it better). If you want to show someone how it's built, show them the circuit with transistors. There's no need to force both to fit on the same diagram if they don't fit.

Comment: Is there something unusual in the ways I am making logic gates? In youtube I also saw logic gates being built in these ways. I can connect output of one into inputs of others for NOT, NAND and NOR gates only. I made an XOR gate using 4 NAND gates ad the following identity XOR (A,B) = NAND ( NAND(A,NAND(A,B)) , NAND (B,NAND(A,B)) )